# Python: How can I use urllib or requests modules from a corporate domain (firewall, proxy, cntlm etc)

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to do the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
data = urlopen("https://www.duolingo.com/users/SaifullahS6").read()
```

I get the following error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Similarly, when I try this:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
data = {"login": "SaifullahS6", "password": "mypassword"}
req = requests.Request('POST', "https://www.duolingo.com/login", data=data,         
cookies=session.cookies)
prepped=req.prepare()
returned = session.send(prepped)
```

I get:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.duolingo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000E6948D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))
```

I am not sure how to give details of my internet connection.

- I'm at work and I know we have a corporate proxy.
- We have Windows Firewall turned on, but i have checked that python and pythonw are ticked in the "Domain" column of the control panel for allowing a program through the firewall.
- When I ping google.co.uk from a command shell, all four requests time out, but I can access it from a browser.
- In the Internet Options control panel, I click on the Connections tab and then LAN settings, and I have "Automatically detect settings" turned on, and also "Use a proxy server for your LAN", "Address" is "localhost" and "Port" is 3128. This is cntlm. I set it up once to do download python packages, and it appears to still be active because I have just managed to update one of my packages.

I don't even need a direct answer to my question; at this point I'll just  settle for some clarity on what is actually going on behind the scenes. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first case above (urllib module), I solved it by inserting the following lines before the `data = urlopen(...).read()` line:

```
proxies = { "http": "localhost:3128",
            "https": "localhost:3128"}
proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

For the second case (requests module), everything was the same except the last line:

```
proxies = { "http": "localhost:3128",
            "https": "localhost:3128"}
returned = session.send(prepped, proxies=proxies)
```

Hope this note helps others who come across this page.